# Detail about parenthesis in a function type declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am currently reading about the identity Monad and one piece defines fmap as this:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (W a -> W b)
fmap f (W x) = W (f x)
```

The text says the goal is creating a function which changes an existing function for the types of a and b to another function which applies the original function to the types W a and W b.

From this point of view there are two functions involved and the type signature also looks like this: Its parameter is one function and it delivers a function.

What puzzled me at first is that the actual type of fmap as ghci tells is:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> W a -> W b
```

Thinking about that reveals that the function fmap gets a function and a parameter of type W a and then applies the function on the a in the W a and returns the result as W b. Which happens to be the description of what the code for fmap does.

I am pretty sure that it does not make any difference in what the function does if one omits the parenthesis in the type definition.

Am I right that this is similar to as if I would say:

`addab` is a function which creates a function that can add a value to its parameter

And give this example code:

```
addab :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
addab x y = x + y

add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 = addab 1
```

Basically just indicating that the function is made to be used without giving all the parameters to it?

Or is there any deeper meaning to it which I did not consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for starters it *can't* make a difference because `->` is right-associative, meaning `(a->b)->c->d` is defined as `(a->b) -> (c->d)`!

As to why and so on, you're exactly right: it's just currying. The particular reason why that is so popular in Haskell is that partial application lends itself very well to writing computation pipelines in a natural way: stuff like `unzip . fmap f . reverse`. Here, the `fmap` doesn't really receive its list argument, only the morphism it's supposed to lift onto lists. The result morphism has a type `([a]->[b])`.

This `(a->b) -> (F a->F d)` is actually the more "fundamental" definition: mathematicians define a functor as mapping morphisms to morphisms; the "function and argument" writing `(a->b, F a) -> F b` generally doesn't make any sense because there is, in general categories, no meaningful wway to combine morphisms with objects. Only, as nomen sais, in *cartesian closed categories* morphisms are objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

Both of those types for `fmap` are correct.  They are effectively equivalent.

And your experiment is correct as well.

What is going on here is that the space of functions is a closed cartesian category.  In particular, this means that we can do partial function application.  It is deep, insofar as there are logics/languages where partial function application is invalid as a rule of inference.  Of course, this means that Haskell has more valid ways to factor a program than other languages.

For example, your `addab` function and a `multab` function you can define yourself let us do things like:

```
addab 1 . addab 2 . multab 3 $ 5
```

Comment: Calling the "space of functions" a "closed cartesian" category is of course a bit imprecise wording. _The category of Haskell types with Haskell functions as morphisms is cartesian closed_ would be more accurate. But spot on, cartesian closedness is precisely what gives **Hask** its powerful currying abilities.